# making a menu item expand when child element is active

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, focus

I have a drop down menu with sub-categories, which is connected to fullscreen.js to navigate sections. As the user scolls down with the mousewheel, the relevant section titles are highlighted in the sidebar menu.

I am trying to make one main category expand automatically when the user scrolls into one of its child sub-catagories, and collapse when the user scrolls into sections 3 or 1.
In the example, it is **Section 2**, which expands when clicked upon.

http://jsfiddle.net/n62t9wfy/1/

I have been trying to use **on ("focus")** to replicate the same effect as the menu being clicked on, when the child's child elements are active, like here:

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('focus', 'li', 'li', '.active', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
});
```

but this has no effect on the code, and looks overly long. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was a mess, I hope I helped a little to break it down a little bit, though it's not as perfect as it could have been.

fiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/n62t9wfy/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/n62t9wfy/4/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idInterval;
    var has_sub = $('.has-sub');
    function openmenu() {
        has_sub.children('.accrd').slideDown();
        has_sub.addClass('opened');
    }
    function closemenu() {
        has_sub.children('.accrd').slideUp();
        has_sub.removeClass('opened');
    }
    $('.has-sub>a').click(function() {
        if ($('.has-sub').hasClass('opened')) {
            closemenu()
        } else {
            openmenu()
        }
    });
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['sec1', 'top1', 'top2', 'top3', 'top4', 'top5', 'sec3', 'sec4', 'sec5', ],
        menu: ".cssmenu",
        sectionsColor: ['blue', 'pink', 'gray', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'black'],
        slidesNavigation: true,
        loopBottom: true,
        'verticalCentered': false,
        afterRender: function() {
            idInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 4500);
        },
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
            if (index == 1) {
                idInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                }, 4500);
            } else {
                clearInterval(idInterval);
            }

            $('.inlinedColor').css('color', 'gray').removeClass('inlinedColor');
            $('li.active').prevAll('span.year').first().add($('li.active').parents('li').find('a span span')).addClass('inlinedColor').css('color', 'black');

            if ($('.accrd li').hasClass('active')) {
                openmenu()
            } else {
                closemenu()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you,yes the code had come from various different sources so was a bit hard to comprehend, this looks much more streamlined.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to put a relation between your "page index" from `afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index)` with your navigation.. Below is my approach:

HTML - see how I add the id to every `<li>` that can be clicked:

```
    <li id="1" data-menuanchor="sec1" class="active"><a href='#sec1'><span>Section 1</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span class="sectitle"><span>Section 2 +</span></span></a>
      <ul>
         <span class="year">Sub cat 1</span>

               <li id="2" data-menuanchor="top1"><a href='#top1'><span class="coltitle">topic 1</span></a></li>
               <li id="3" data-menuanchor="top2"><a href='#top2'><span class="coltitle">topic 2</span></a></li>


         <span class="year">Sub cat 2</span>

               <li id="4" data-menuanchor="top3"><a href='#top3'><span class="coltitle">topic 3</span></a></li>
               <li id="5" data-menuanchor="top4"><a href='#top4'><span class="coltitle">topic 4</span></a></li>
               <li id="6" data-menuanchor="top5"><a href='#top5'><span class="coltitle">topic 5</span></a></li>


       </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="7" data-menuanchor="sec3"><a href='#sec3'><span class="sectitle"><span>Section 3</span></span></a></li>
```

jQuery:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                selected = $("#menutab").find("li#"+index);
                alert(selected.parents("li.has-sub").length);
                if(selected.parents("li.has-sub").length == 1){
                    //put your expand code here, I'm not sure how you expand your nav
                    element = selected.parents("li.has-sub");
                    element.addClass('open');
                }
                //rest code is omitted
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n62t9wfy/2/), as you slide through it will look whether your selected page is a child of `has-sub` class. It will return 1 if it's a part of sub menu.